# Vary parameters with slider

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am trying basically to create an excel table using Anylogic. The idea is to introduce all the parameters/variables in the system and then make basic calculations between them and show all the results in a table. What I am trying to do also is to add a slider and be able to vary the values of the parameters and see how the values change in the table  while the simulation is running.In the image it can be seen what I am trying, I used a parameter and a variable but neither of them is working as I wanted.
[Image of the blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzbPa.png)

It will probably be a basic problem but I am struggling a bit with it , so a little help will be appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You are not asking a question but simply say "it does not work". Please refine this to make our lives easy :) I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways in which you can change the value of a parameter or variable using a slider:
the first one is linking the slider to a variable:
[image: slider properties]

The second one is to use the action of the slider:

```
//value is a local variable of the slider action that holds the slider selection
set_parameter(value);
variable=value;
```